# How do I remove an entry from the Format > Stylesheet menu?

Tags: front-end, stylesheet

I was playing a bit with the stylesheets to make my own. In the process I have created and installed a few stylesheets but now I would like to remove some of them.

First, how do I remove an entry from the Format > Stylesheet menu?

Second, where are the stylesheet files kept? I have deleted the files from the `$UserBaseDirectory/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/StyleSheets`, reloaded *Mathematica*, even rebooted the computer, but my styles are still working! Apparently *Mathematica* keeps a copy of my files somewhere I don't know about.

Comment: You mean you want to remove the ones that come with your copy of Mathematica? If so, then check in `$InstallationDirectory` (the directory tree is the same)

Comment: How did you create and install these in the first place?

Comment: No, I wanted to remove the stylesheet I created and installed. I did it by selecting Format/Edit Stylesheet, modifying the some styles and clicking the Install Stylesheet button. My new style appeared on the menu list and the corresponding nb file in the $UserBaseDirectory.... Removing the file from this directory does not remove the entry form the list and does not remove the style. For the solution see below

Comment: You *may* also need to restart Mathematica with a clean cache. See http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/TroubleshootingMathematica.html (or its equivalent in the Documentation Center).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To my knowledge just removing the stylesheet file should be enough. The places where *Mathematica* looks for stylesheets can be extracted using `CurrentValue`

```
CurrentValue["StyleSheetPath"]
(*
{FrontEnd`FileName[{$UserBaseDirectory,Autoload,_,FrontEnd,StyleSheets}],
FrontEnd`FileName[{$UserBaseDirectory,Applications,_,FrontEnd,StyleSheets}],
FrontEnd`FileName[{$BaseDirectory,Autoload,_,FrontEnd,StyleSheets}],
FrontEnd`FileName[{$BaseDirectory,Applications,_,FrontEnd,StyleSheets}],
FrontEnd`FileName[{$InstallationDirectory,AddOns,Autoload,_,FrontEnd,StyleSheets}],
FrontEnd`FileName[{$InstallationDirectory,AddOns,Applications,_,FrontEnd,StyleSheets}],
FrontEnd`FileName[{$UserBaseDirectory,SystemFiles,FrontEnd,StyleSheets}],
FrontEnd`FileName[{$BaseDirectory,SystemFiles,FrontEnd,StyleSheets}],
FrontEnd`FileName[{$InstallationDirectory,Configuration,FrontEnd,StyleSheets}],
FrontEnd`FileName[{$InstallationDirectory,SystemFiles,FrontEnd,StyleSheets}]}
*)
```

The directory names with an underscore point to locations where several packages could be placed. Every package can have it's own `FrontEnd` directory, etc. IMO. The other paths are are fixed and you can extract all stylesheets there by using something like

```
FileNames["*.nb", 
 Cases[FileNameJoin @@@ CurrentValue["StyleSheetPath"], _String]]
```

### How to find all stylesheets

As one can see the above output of `CurrentValue` contains paths with a `_`.

```
FrontEnd`FileName[{$UserBaseDirectory,Autoload,_,FrontEnd,StyleSheets}]
```

Here the `_` stands for every possible directory. You can use a small function which transforms a single `FrontEnd`FileName[..]`into valid input for`FileNames`

```
makeFileNamesInput[FrontEnd`FileName[cont_]] :=
 If[FreeQ[cont, Verbatim[_]],
  {"*.nb", {FileNameJoin[cont]}},
  cont /. {dir__, Verbatim[_], rest__} :> (FileNameJoin /@ {{"*", rest, "*.nb"}, {dir}})
]
```

And now you can search all possible directories for style-sheet notebooks

```
Flatten[FileNames[##, Infinity] & @@@ 
  makeFileNamesInput /@ CurrentValue["StyleSheetPath"]]
```

### Better alternative

I don't now why I haven't used it when I wrote the answer, but there's a much faster alternative to find all stylesheets in all directories given by `CurrentValue["StyleSheetPath"]`. Although, `ToFileName` seems to be superseded by `FileNameJoin`, this function can transform all `` FrontEnd`FileName ``-directories returned by `CurrentValue` directly into valid path specifications. Therefore, when I haven't missed anything, you should find all stylesheets by

```
FileNames["*.nb", (ToFileName /@ CurrentValue["StyleSheetPath"]), Infinity]
```

Comment: Thanks! The problem is solved but I still do not understand it. I run your second command to get the list of all stylesheets and I see that my own styles are sitting in the

Comment: sorry, my previous comment broke. I continue: I found my stylesheet files in the directory C:\ProgramData\Mathematica\SystemFiles\FrontEnd\StyleSheets. Removing these files removes the corresponding entries from the Format/StyleSheet menu - this is what I wanted! However, this ProgramData directory does not appear on the list generated by your first command!? $UserBaseDirectory, $BaseDirectory, and $InstallationDirectory point somewhere else.

Comment: @MarekPfutzner Can you join the chat here [http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6138/diskussion-between-halirutan-and-marek](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6138/diskussion-between-halirutan-and-marek)